# make another variable dependent on the value of another variable

Tags: r, variables, frame

Im trying to create a new variable that is dependent on another variables value.

This is how my data looks like.

```
 work <- read.table(header=T, text="ID incident
1   1     <NA>
2   2     2006
3   3     1997
4   4     <NA>
5   5     1994
6   6     1998
7   7     <NA>
8   9     <NA>
9  10     1988
10 11     <NA>")
```

This is how i want it to look like

```
read.table(header=T, text="ID   Incident    Incident1
1   NA      0
2   2006    0
3   1997    1
4   NA      0
5   1994    1
6   1998    0
7   NA      0
8   NA      0
9   NA      0
10  1988    1")
```

This means that i want to make a new variable for "incident", calling it "incident1" and this variable will only take on the value of 1 if "incident" has the value of less than 1998.

That means every value in "incident" <1998 will give "incident1"=1 all else will receive a zero.

I've tried this so far `work$incident1[work$incident %in% <1998] <- 1` and it doesn't work.

This is probably an extremely simple question just that i haven't written any code for so long (trying to start gain) and kinda forgot plenty.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: `with(work, ifelse(incident < 1998 & !is.na(incident), 1, 0))` should do it

Comment: This one worked beautifully! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `factor` variable "incident" in the "work" dataset to `numeric` class ("incid").  You can do it either by `as.numeric(as.character(` or `as.numeric(levels(...`, and then apply the condition `incid < 1998 &..`

```
incid <- as.numeric(as.character(work$incident)
```

Or

```
incid <- with(work, as.numeric(levels(incident))[incident])

(incid < 1998 & !is.na(incid))+0
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
work <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L
), incident = structure(c(6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
6L), .Label = c("1988", "1994", "1997", "1998", "2006", "<NA>"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "incident"), class =  
"data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: @Frank49 It is based on the example you provided and it works for me

Comment: @Frank49 No problem.  It seems that your original dataset may not be factor as you showed in the example because if I use that data with Richard's code, it gives all NAs.  `with(work, ifelse(incident < 1998 & !is.na(incident), 1, 0))#
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: My bad, both examples work just fine! To quick to judge it. Thanks @akrun!